# CDI injected objects null in AWS Lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, quarkus

I'm using Java/Quarkus/SAM CLI and am trying to use CDI injection but every @Inject object is evaluating to null.

One example of this is trying to inject an EntityManager:

```
package com.nicnac.software;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.json.bind.Jsonb;
import javax.json.bind.JsonbBuilder;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.ValidationException;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import com.nicnac.software.lambda.ProcessingService;
import com.nicnac.software.models.ServicePayload;
import com.nicnac.software.models.ServicePayloadExecutorResult;

@ApplicationScoped
public class FeedbackProcessingService extends ProcessingService {
    @Inject
    EntityManager em;
    public FeedbackProcessingService() {
                System.out.println(em);
                    }
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public ServicePayloadExecutorResult execute(ServicePayload payload) {
        Comment comment1 = new Comment();
        comment1.suggestions="suggestions";
        System.out.println("heLLO");
        System.out.println("heLLO_1");
        System.out.println("heLLo_2");
        long result = 1L;
        System.out.println(em);
        em.persist(comment1);
        System.out.println("comment: " + comment1.suggestions);
        return new ServicePayloadExecutorResult(result, payload);
    }
}
```

The output from running `sam local invoke` is the following:

```
__  ____  __  _____   ___  __ ____  ______
 --/ __ \/ / / / _ | / _ \/ //_/ / / / __/
 -/ /_/ / /_/ / __ |/ , _/ ,< / /_/ /\ \
--\___\_\____/_/ |_/_/|_/_/|_|\____/___/
2020-07-02 19:49:49,254 INFO  [io.agr.pool] (main) Datasource '<default>': Initial size smaller than min. Connections will be created when necessary
19:49:51.456 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector - -Dio.netty.leakDetection.level: simple
19:49:51.456 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector - -Dio.netty.leakDetection.targetRecords: 4
19:49:51.514 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap - -Dio.netty.threadLocalMap.stringBuilder.initialSize: 1024
19:49:51.514 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap - -Dio.netty.threadLocalMap.stringBuilder.maxSize: 4096    
19:49:51.547 [main] DEBUG io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup - -Dio.netty.eventLoopThreads: 4
19:49:51.647 [main] DEBUG io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop - -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization: false
19:49:51.647 [main] DEBUG io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop - -Dio.netty.selectorAutoRebuildThreshold: 512
19:49:51.675 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - org.jctools-core.MpscChunkedArrayQueue: available
19:49:51.992 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-3] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.numHeapArenas: 4      
19:49:51.992 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-3] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.numDirectArenas: 4    
19:49:51.992 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-3] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.pageSize: 8192        
19:49:51.992 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-3] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.maxOrder: 1
19:49:51.992 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-3] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.chunkSize: 16384      
19:49:51.993 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-3] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.tinyCacheSize: 512    
19:49:51.993 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-3] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.smallCacheSize: 256   
19:49:51.993 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-3] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.normalCacheSize: 64   
19:49:51.993 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-3] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.maxCachedBufferCapacity: 32768
19:49:51.993 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-3] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.cacheTrimInterval: 8192
19:49:51.994 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-3] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.cacheTrimIntervalMillis: 0
19:49:51.994 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-3] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.useCacheForAllThreads: true
19:49:51.994 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-3] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.maxCachedByteBuffersPerChunk: 1023
19:49:52.176 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-3] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil - -Dio.netty.allocator.type: pooled
19:49:52.177 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-3] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil - -Dio.netty.threadLocalDirectBufferSize: 0
19:49:52.177 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-3] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil - -Dio.netty.maxThreadLocalCharBufferSize: 16384        
19:49:52.181 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-3] DEBUG io.netty.util.NetUtil - -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack: true
19:49:52.181 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-3] DEBUG io.netty.util.NetUtil - -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses: false
19:49:52.183 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-3] DEBUG io.netty.util.NetUtil - Loopback interface: lo (lo, 127.0.0.1)
19:49:52.185 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-3] DEBUG io.netty.util.NetUtil - /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn: 128
2020-07-02 19:49:52,471 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) default-lambda-function 1.0-SNAPSHOT on JVM (powered by Quarkus 1.5.2.Final) started in 10.716s. Listening on: http://0.0.0.0:8080
2020-07-02 19:49:52,472 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Profile prod activated.
2020-07-02 19:49:52,473 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Installed features: [agroal, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-lambda, cdi, hibernate-orm, 
jdbc-mariadb, mutiny, narayana-jta, resteasy, resteasy-jsonb, resteasy-mutiny, servlet]
START RequestId: 11d488e6-3311-1b2e-2228-1d9cd5fcb8f0 Version: $LATEST
null
heLLO
heLLO_1
heLLo_2
null
END RequestId: 11d488e6-3311-1b2e-2228-1d9cd5fcb8f0
REPORT RequestId: 11d488e6-3311-1b2e-2228-1d9cd5fcb8f0     Init Duration: 11431.91 ms      Duration: 1853.60 ms    Billed Dura
tion: 1900 ms   Memory Size: 512 MB     Max Memory Used: 154 MB
```

I've confirmed that the database is connecting. Here's the format of my application.properties:

```
quarkus.lambda.handler=lambdaprocessor
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=mariadb
quarkus.datasource.username=root
quarkus.datasource.password=root
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:mariadb://192.168.1.4:3306/backend
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.min-size=4
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.max-size=16
```

Comment: How does `FeedbackProcessingService` get instantiated?

Comment: agreed with @Sean, it seams the `FeedbackProcessingService` is not `@Inject`ed but maybe just intantiated via constructor? The `em` to be `null` during construction is fine. If you need to work with `em` on intantiation then use the callback `@PostConsruct`